# How can I see messages those are acknowledged and those are not or an outstanding messages in Google Cloud Pub/Sub?

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-cloud-functions, cloud, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using Google Cloud Pub/Sub to publish a message on a topic and trigger the cloud function using IClountEventHandler however I want  to validate messages are getting acknowledged or not. So, where do I find in Gcp Pub/Sub?

I am using .net core 3.1 , Goggle cloud function and Google Cloud Pub/Sub.

Is there anywhere on the GCP Web UI I can find those messages status?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get per-message status in Cloud Pub/Sub. The closest you can get is to [monitor your message backlog](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/monitoring#monitoring_the_backlog), including `oldest_unacked_message_age` and `num_undelivered_messages` to understand if messages are being consumed successfully.

There are also several metrics to monitor on the [push subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/monitoring#monitoring_push_subscriptions) for the Cloud Function. This subscription got created when you created the Cloud Function. In particular, you may want to look at the `push_request_count` metric and group by `response_code` to ensure that successful responses are being sent for the messages your subscriber receives.

You can find the subscription by going to the topic details page for the topic to which you are subscribing and look for the subscription named `gcf-<function name>-<region>-<topic name>`.